# GlassFish v3.0.1 ignoring sun-web.xml

Tags: web-services, web-applications, glassfish, war

I have a WAR (extendedname1.01.war) and I have set up a sun-web.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Sun ONE Application         
Server 7.0 Servlet 2.3//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/sunone/appserver/dtds/sun- web-app_2_3-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app>
   <context-root>/app</context-root>
 </sun-web-app>
```

When I deploy the war it ignores the context in my sun-web.xml and leaves the context root as /extendedname1.01.

The sun-web.xml is in the WEB-INF/ folder of my war.

Can anyone shed any light on this please?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with the admin GUI tool.
You should deploy your application through the command line `asadmin` tool:
for example:

```
./asadmin deploy extendedname1.01
```